# Cloudwatch log service combining logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm looking at [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cloudwatch-log-service/) for configuring log services on a linux AWS machine. If I wanted to view logs from different machines, would all the logs show up in one place in my console or do I have to go to each machine separately. On a smaller scale, can I search logs by specific files I listed to keep track of logs from?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The correct way to search the logs over multiple instances would be to hit the "Search Group" button after you click on the Log Group. This will collate the various log streams.

Continue to use the instance id/name as the log stream.

The previous answer is incorrect, and will cause issues related to sequencing of logs and idempotency. This includes the possibility of an losing logs if 5 requests with an invalid sequence token occur in a row.